# Analytic vs discrete understanding of PDE

Tags: discretization, numerics, parabolic-pde, linear-system

The PDE I am working with:

$$\partial_tu = \nabla \cdot (a(x)\nabla u)-\beta(x)u\\
\partial_nu=0, x \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2\\
\beta(x)>0$$

1. Integrate the PDE:

$$\int_\Omega \partial_t u=\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot (a(x)\nabla u)dx-\int_\Omega \beta(x)udx$$

2. Apply the Divergence theorem:

$$\int_\Omega \partial_t u=\int_{\partial\Omega} a(x)\nabla u\cdot nds-\int_\Omega \beta(x)udx$$

3. Apply the Neuman boundary condition:

$$\int_\Omega \partial_t u=\int_{\partial\Omega} a(x)\partial_n uds-\int_\Omega \beta(x)udx=-\int_\Omega \beta(x)udx$$

4. Obtain a new PDE:

$$\partial_t u+\beta(x)u=0$$

This PDE is in essence an ODE, so we can get the following solution for this ODE:

$$u(x,t)=e^{-\beta(x)t}D(x),$$
where $D(x)$ is an integration "constant".

5. Discretize the ODE. After discretization I should obtain a linear system of the following form:

$$\frac{du}{dt}=Au - c$$

But when I discretize this system I obtain the following:
$$\frac{du_{ij}}{dt}=-\beta_{ij} u_{ij}$$

So one could say that $A$ in this case has the form diag$(-\beta_{ij}, \dots, -\beta_{ij})$, but then where is the vector $c$ coming from?

Also, one could observe that, since $\beta(x)>0$, 
$$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} u(x,t) = 0$$.
But how can we deduce the same from the discretized system?

Comment: You can't go from 3. to 4. Just because the integrals on the left and right are equal does not imply that the *integrands* are equal pointwise. In fact, they will in general not be.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I understand what you mean, but I think it's a standard argument from the derivation of the diffusion equation and conservation laws that if the integral is zero on the entire domain of $\Omega$ then it must necessarily be true that we can deduce 4 from 3. The reason is that $\Omega$ is arbitrary, so pointwise the integrands must coincide.

Comment: How is $\Omega$ arbitrary if it is the domain of the PDE in the description of the PDE up at the top?

Comment: Like @Kirill already states, it's definitely not a standard argument :-) The standard argument is that if $\int_\omega f(x)\, dx = 0$ for *any* arbitrarily chosen $\omega$, then $f(x)$ in the $L_1$ sense. But you don't have this statement for any arbitrary $\omega$ -- you only have it for one very particular $\Omega$.

Comment: But this $\Omega$ is not specified, it does not appear to be specific at all. It is only given that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, so isn't it true that $\Omega$ can be quite arbitrary?

Comment: If you require zero Neumann boundary condition for arbitrary domain $\Omega$ it sounds like prescribing zero diffusion "pointwise" everywhere ...

Comment: In other words, if you want this $\Omega$ to be arbitrary (and different from the domain on which the PDE is posed), then you can't argue that the boundary terms of the equation in 3. should be zero.

Comment: Why can't I pick an arbitrary domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and prescribe that on this arbitrary $\Omega$ the boundary condition is always zero? That is, if each domain $\Omega$ has a boundary then the boundary condition applies only to that boundary. The boundary condition is not prescribed in explicit terms, nor is $\Omega$ prescribed explicitly. If we pick an arbitrary domain $\Omega$ then it will have arbitrary boundary, and the boundary condition will apply only to this boundary of this $\Omega$ that we picked. See http://www.math.utep.edu/Faculty/sewell/tamu/664/prob4b.pdf

Comment: If you write that out in full, the condition you’re describing is $\nabla u=0$. That’s just not how boundary conditions work, generally speaking, they are fixed once, at the moment the pde is specified, and the domain is only arbitrary to the extent that the pde definition gives it to you and you don’t know what it is, but it is not arbitrary in the way you describe.

Comment: @Kirill Thanks for clarifying. Can you please comment on the zero integrand approach in this text?  math.utep.edu/Faculty/sewell/tamu/664/prob4b.pdf There integration happens on an arbitrary subregion of the domain. We can divide $\Omega$ into such arbitrary subregions.